# Note 5 No SIM Card, No WI-FI and invalid imei after flashing LineageOS 16 and HyperKernel

Tags: samsung-mobile, android-9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy, custom-rom

Thanks for care of my problem.
i have Samsung glaxy note 5(SM-N920C) and im flashed android 9 custom rom for s6+ and hyperkernel. after flashing them, my phone's imei is gone ,i cant use wifi and phone is not dedectimg SIM.
i was try installing random imei but it didnt worked.
what should i do? for fix this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: so where should i ask this to

Comment: @Mat FYI, this question is covered by the standard close reason for "general computing hardware and software."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im solved it with flashing android 9 kernel for sm-n920c